# 3d (THREE.js) : difference matrix

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to save the info that represents the relative difference between two THREE.Object3d. I prefer to save the data as a transformation matrix.

Can someone knows what do i need to do to get this?

I would like to have a matrix4 that later on i could apply on an object and it will  move/rotate by the same values.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have two transformations A and B you are looking for the transformation T that transforms A into B, right? Formally this is written as

B = T · A

Now you can think of going from A to B, as going back from A to identity (I) and then from identity to B i.e.

Going back from A to I:

I = inv(A) · A

Going from I to B

B = B · I

Chaining that up you get

B = B · inv(A) · A

Add a few parentheses to highlight things:

B = ( B · inv(A) ) · A

Comparing that with the first equation we see that

T = B · inv(A)

Comment: That worked! Now, when i apply the T matrix on the first Object, it becoming to look like the second. @datenwolf

Answer (score 1):

For each object you can do a

```
matrix.decompose( position, quaternion, scale )
```

to get back the position, quaternion and scale and then for the quaternion you can do

```
matrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion( quaternion )
```

and then store the appropriate differences you need.

Comment: so 1st i calculate the position/rotation/scale difference between the two, then do the two lines of code you wrote? than i need to apply this matrix on another? @gaitat