# Find transformation matrix between two matrices

Tags: math, three.js, matrix-multiplication

I tried to find the transformation matrix between two matrices, so i can save it, and later apply it on an object so it will maintain its position and rotation relatively to another object. using this sugested solution:

[3d (THREE.js) : difference matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960768/3d-three-js-difference-matrix)

I used this code:

```
var aInv1 = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(firstObject.matrix.clone());
var aMat2 = new THREE.Matrix4().copy(secondObject.matrix.clone());
var aTrans = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(aMat2, aInv1);
```

The values of the matrices elements are:

```
firstObject.matrix.elements = [ 
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, -358.483421667927, 1
]

secondObject.matrix.elements = [
    0.5137532240102918, -0.844167465362402, 0.15309773101731067, 0,
    0.8579380075617532, 0.5055071032079361, -0.091678480502733, 0,
    -1.3877787807814457e-17, 0.1784484772418605, 0.983949257314655, 0,
    94.64320536824728, 6.92473686011361, -372.0695450875709, 1
]
```

I would expect that the transformation Matrix aka variable `aTrans` elements would be `94.64320536824728, 6.92473686011361, 13.58` because those are the differences in the position, but I get `94.64320536824728, 70.89555757320696, -19.340048577797802, 1`.

```
aTrans.matrix.elements = [
    0.5137532240102918, -0.844167465362402, 0.15309773101731067, 0,
    0.8579380075617532, 0.5055071032079361, -0.091678480502733, 0,
    -1.3877787807814457e-17, 0.1784484772418605, 0.983949257314655, 0,
    94.64320536824728, 70.89555757320696, -19.340048577797802, 1
]
```

I would appriciate any educated explanation for this difference, or another way to solve this problem.

Comment: Just pointing out to anyone who gets here via the math/matrix tags, three.js uses column-major matrices (not that it should matter in this instance).

Comment: Can you compute `aTrans.aMat1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply add the translations because the second matrix might affect the *effective* translation of the first.

Let's consider a simple example - suppose both matrices only contain a rotation and translation:

```
M = R + T
```

`R` corresponds to the top-left 3x3 sub-matrix, and `T` is the first 3 elements of the last column. Multiplication rule with an arbitrary 3D point `p`:

```
M * p = R * p + T
```

Two of these give:

```
M2 * M1 * p = R2 * R1 * p + R2 * T1 + T2
```

The last column of `M2 * M1` is `R2 * T1 + T2` instead of simply `T1 + T2`, i.e. *effective* translation that `M1` imposes on `p` is `R2 * T1`, and not simply `T1`.

Comment: What do you meen by (p) ?

Comment: @tlatis any point that you want to transform with the matrix.